# Django: get_readonly_fields does not return correctly

Tags: python, django

I would like to ask some assistance in this matter, I would like to set the fields in the admin `readonly` via `get_readonly_fields` depending on the model's `APP_STATUS`

my code:

```
def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
    if obj.APP_STATUS != 1 :
        return self.readonly_fields + ['PRE_FINAL_INTERVIEW_EXAM_SCORE', 'PRE_FINAL_INTERVIEW_EXAM_SCORE_STATUS', 'COMMENT_ON_INITIAL_EVALUATION']
    elif obj.APP_STATUS != 4 :
        return self.readonly_fields + ['POST_TRAINING_EVALUATION_EXAM_SCORE', 'POST_TRAINING_EVALUATION_EXAM_SCORE_STATUS', 'COMMENT_ON_TRAINING_EVALUATION']
    return self.readonly_fields
```

the problem is that only the first `if` is being rendered as read only, what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't make sense of the question. What do you mean by "the first if is being rendered as read only,"? What is the expected behaviour? And what actually happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't be done the `if` branching using `!=` because the conditions doesn't exclude each other: let's say `obj.APP_STATUS = 2`, this validates both conditions `if obj.APP_STATUS != 1` and `if obj.APP_STATUS != 4` and whichever is first that will be run.